# Observing decrements in values in a column using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I am very new to VBA and programming. I need to count the number of times the value decreases from the previous value in a row within a MS Access column. I created an Access form with a dialogue box which shows the output of the VBA code. Following is an example of the program:

So for the following snapshot of the column with entries: [23, 34, 22, 55, 65, 34, 77, 24, 30, 29]. The output (at the form dialogue box) of the intended program  for this column is 4 because the value in a column decreases 4 times from the previous value.

[image: Example]

Comment: This seems like an interesting task you are having - try to simplify it a bit, by dividing it into two separate tasks - read the entries and save them to an array or collection. Then loop through this collection and count the number of decrementing values.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can think to do this presumes you know the proper ordering of the row, which involves (in a logical sense) some other column that is monotonically increasing. Assume that is Field1, the primary key. Then something like this would work: (lv = left-val, rv = right-val)

```
select
     lv.Field2 as HigherVal
   , rv.Field2 as LowerVal
from MyTable as lv
inner join MyTable as rv
    on lv.Field1 = rv.Field1 + 1
where
     lv.Field2 > rv.Field2

or to get counts...

select
     count()
from MyTable as lv
inner join MyTable as rv
    on lv.Field1 = rv.Field1 + 1
where
     lv.Field2 > rv.Field2
```

If you don't have that monotonic Field1, you'll have to add a ranking field (ranking 1, 2, 3, 4, ...) that establishes the proper order of the data, and does so with no gaps in it.

Comment: Just wondering - if you try with the OP's data, does it work?

Comment: Call me a confident guy... I wrote it without running it. :)

Comment: This assumes `Field1` is a continuous autonumber field (no missing values). You can rewrite it to remove that assumption, and only assume `Field1` is a field you can order by.

Comment: Yes, that's true, as I did note from the get-go. However when you remove that requirement, your join becomes a lot more complicated, and the SQL less efficient. You'll have to require rv.Field1 to be greater than lv.Field1 *and* less than all other possible Field1 values from the same table that are also greater than lv.Field1. That's unpleasant SQL, though it can (granted) be done.

Comment: Vitiyata provides a nice approach if you wish to solve the problem via a VBA approach. If you wish to solve it via SQL, and you do not have a monotonic ranking field in hand, this link provides the method by which you'd solve the problem with one (no longer quite so) simple SQL statement: https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/ranking-in-ms-access/

Comment: (After a bit more reflection...) The VBA solution sounds great until you realize you are not escaping the use of SQL. You cannot magically create the array pre-loaded. You may as well make your recordset (the one you'd need anyway to load the array) give you your answer directly. I won't implement the ranking feature, but the link I provided previously shows how to build the ranking into subqueries, at which point my proposed solution is the shorter and faster route to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I try not to answer questions where the `OP` has not tried anything, but in this case I will make an exception:

1. Try to convert your column to array.
2. Once you have the array, simply loop through it:

.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    '2
    Debug.Print CountDecrements(Array(1, 2, 3, 2))

    '-1,-3, 5
    Debug.Print CountDecrements(Array(1, -1, -3, 100, 101, 5))

End Sub

Public Function CountDecrements(myArray As Variant) As Long

    Dim k               As Double
    Dim previousValue   As Double
    Dim result          As Long

    For k = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If k = LBound(myArray) Then
            previousValue = myArray(k)
        Else
            If previousValue > myArray(k) Then result = result + 1
            previousValue = myArray(k)
        End If
    Next k

    CountDecrements = result

End Function
```

The `CountDecrement()` function simply counts how many times the previous value is smaller than the current one. The result is saved in the `result` variable.